# List out files inside folder in S3 bucket using minio

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I am trying to read files from S3 bucket using minio client.

https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-quickstart-guide.html

I am able to make connection using this client and able to access the bucket also. Now, I need to access a file  inside a folder in the bucket but I am not sure how to do it. I thought once I have access to the bucket, I can list out the file names using File library but not able to do it.

*File path : s3 bucket endpoint/4275/input/test.csv*

**Code :**

```
public void listS3BucketObject() {
        MinioClient minioClient =
                MinioClient.builder()
                        .endpoint(s3BucketEndpoint)
                        .credentials(s3BucketAccessKey, s3BucketSecretKey)
                        .build();

        String fileUrl = s3BucketEndpoint + "/" + "4275" + "/" + "input";
    
        File[] fileList =  new File(fileUrl).listFiles();
        for(File file : fileList) {
                      System.out.println("File name: "+file.getName()); // getting null exception here
```

Answer (score 2):

To list a "folder" (called a prefix in S3 terms), use the listObjects call.

See this for an example: https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-api-reference.html#listObjects

Comment: There's no documentation about how to access files in specific path.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with that also as there is no good documentation.
As written in @sh0dan answer you have to use `listObject` with prefix, but the prefix HAS TO END with `/`. e.g. `data/` or `data/subfolder1/` This will list folder.
Here is my working code (its a rest method but you should get the idea):

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("buckets/{bucket}/{filepath : .+}")
    public JsonObject getItem(@PathParam("bucket") String bucket,
                              @PathParam("filepath") String filepath) {

        MinioClient minioClient = getMinioClient();

        // Lists objects information.
        Iterable<Result<Item>> results = minioClient.listObjects(
            ListObjectsArgs.builder().bucket(bucket).prefix(filepath).build());

        JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null);
        JsonObjectBuilder builder = factory.createObjectBuilder();
        JsonArrayBuilder itemArrayBuilder = factory.createArrayBuilder();
        builder.add("items", itemArrayBuilder);

        for (Result<Item> result : results) {
            try {
                Item item = result.get();
                itemArrayBuilder.add(factory.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", item.objectName())
                .add("isdir", item.isDir())
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        JsonArray jsonArray = itemArrayBuilder.build();
        builder.add("items", jsonArray);
        JsonObject jsonObject = builder.build();
        return jsonObject;
    }
```